# How to solve migration problem in ASP.NET Core MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am learning to create web applications. First of all, I went through the tutorial on creating a web application with Movies on the Microsoft site, and everything worked out. But when I started to create an application in my own subject area, I ran into a migration problem. The problem is that as a result of the migration, I get an error, that I do not have a definition for the 'Movie'.

> Error CS1061: 'AlbumContext' does not contain a definition for 'Movie' and no accessible extension method 'Movie' accepting a first argument of type 'AlbumContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It should be added that I get the database connection string automatically as a result of scaffolding.

There is my Model:

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

Generated controller. There is nothing special, just simple CRUD methods. But first it was created, there was wrong return statements in Index method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
          return _context.Movie != null ? 
                      View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync()) :
                      Problem("Entity set 'MvcAlbumeContext.Album'  is null.");
    }
```

Instead of this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
          return _context.Album != null ? 
                      View(await _context.Album.ToListAsync()) :
                      Problem("Entity set 'MvcAlbumeContext.Album'  is null.");
    }
```

Simple context:

```
public class MvcAlbumeContext : DbContext
{
    public MvcAlbumeContext (DbContextOptions<MvcAlbumeContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MvcAlbum.Models.Album>? Album { get; set; }
}
```

And connection string from appsettings:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MvcAlbumeContext": "Data Source=MvcAlbumeContext-b15b56a9-dd3b-4d6a-870d-0c0872252605.db"
```

}

Comment: We need to see the code that generates the error. This is not related to Visual Studio or Mac or anything like that. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mre]

Comment: Please add your code, specifically Program.cs file

Comment: Can you check migration folder under your project? Does everything seems ok there?

Comment: @SlobodanT There is no migration folder. As I know, It creates folder if the migration is success

Comment: `'AlbumContext' does not contain a definition for 'Movie'` which is correct. Your `MvcAlbumeContext` only defines `DbSet<Album>? Album` and not `DbSet<Movie>? Movie` (or whatever you want)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JeremyLakerman But what does that mean? The fact is that I don’t need the Movie model, I only need the Album model. Why do I get Movie variables in the controller as a result of scaffolding and can't migrate my Album model?

Answer (score 0):

> But first it was created, there was wrong return statements in Index
> method

I also encountered this problem of yours before, but I replaced the `movie` to my class (`Album`) in Context,  and  migrated, and then there is no problem, you can try it.